# Breaking up a sprite in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a 2D plane fighting game for the iPhone in cocos2d. I'm trying to make it so when you shoot an enemy plane, it breaks into a couple of separated pieces that will fall out of sight. What is generally the best practice for breaking one sprite up into many? should I create new images for each separate piece, or treat the initial image like a sprite sheet, and make a new sprite from segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please look at this tutorial](http://headlightinc.com/shatter-sample-src.zip)

It makes a grid of points then moves the internal (not-edge) ones around randomly a bit so it's not all perfect triangles. Then each update it moves/rotates the triangles separately--then draws them all at once.

You treat the whole thing as a sprite, so can run any of the usual actions on it. This example uses CCMoveBy to move the whole group down off the bottom.

Comment: I would like if your thanks comes in form of vote up...welcome..:)

Comment: Its ok dude..was kidding..enjoy